# Full list of YouTube search parameters? Goal: Search within a certain channel

Tags: search, youtube

I could not find a complete reference for **all** YouTube search parameters.

I stumbled upon `intitle` and `allintitle` as well as the operators `+word` and `-word`. And the `"exact search"` which is by the way not really working in YouTube.

Is there an official reference somewhere?

My goal is to search only within a certain channel by using a query from an iframe embed.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the *Custom query parameters for the YouTube Data API* in the YouTube API documentation is of any help, where you can find other parameters than q, which you can add to a search-query URL if you do it over the API URL. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters

**Some other in-query operators for the q parameter:**

```
 - your search term, -channel
   omit channels
 - lady gaga -"bad romance"
   omit string with spaces
 - term1 +term2
   requires both terms in the results
 - *, live
   find anything that is live
```

And no, there is no official list of those in-query parameters. You need to dig them and try it. Google tries to decrease it's usage and instead improve their algorithm for natural language search queries, instead of letting people search in a non-human way.

**Sources:**

http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2277383/Google-Kills-Tilde-Search-Operator

http://searchengineland.com/google-sunsets-search-operator-98189

http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2120272/Google-Subtracts-Advanced-Search-Operator

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/3oIWbew9xdE%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hope somebody can dig out the parameter to filter the search restricted to the "author" (youtube channel)!